# 05 Honda Odyssey heater only works after low

Tags: honda, heater, odyssey, heater-core

I have a 2005 Honda Odyssey. The heater system has been working very odd as of late. When the car gets up to temperature the heater even on high only blows out icy cold air. However, if you turn the AC to low then turn the heat back up the heater now blows hot. I have recently had a reverse flush on the heater core. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Thank you,
Travis

Comment: Do you have an auto climate feature in your Odyssey? (ie: set temp to 72° F and the system keeps it there.)

Comment: Yes, the car does have that feature

Comment: I would bet the issue lies in the climate control. There may be a procedure to reset it (I know there is for GM vehicles, so assume there might be one for Hondas as well).